# bolt cms file paths file

Tags: file, templates, twig, bolt-cms

I i'm trying to get a list of all the files from a filelist contenttype to display in an unordered list. But I have not been able to get the file location `{{ record.file }}` to work. I have fixed this temporally by posting the `{{ record.title }}` where the `{{ record.file }}` should be.

```
                        <ul>

                        {% set filerecord = record.file() %}

                            {% if record.file is not empty %}

                                {% for record in filerecord %}

                                    <li><i class="fa fa-file-pdf-o"></i><a href="{{ paths.files }}{{ record.file }}" title="Download">{{ record.title }}</a></li>

                                {% endfor %}

                            {% endif %}

                        </ul>
```

This piece of code below does get the filename, but only works for the contenttype file and not filelist as it is an array.

```
{% for key,value in record.values if key in ['templatefields'] %}


<span><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>Oplevering |</span>
<span>{{ record.starts_at }} /</span>
<span>{{ record.ends_at }} |</span>

{% set filerecord = record.file() %}

{% if filerecord is not empty %}<span><i class="fa fa-file-pdf-o"></i><a href="{{ paths.files }}{{ record.file }}" title="Download de folder">Download de folder</a></span>{% endif %}


{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 1):

I took some more google time and dug through the documentation of bolt.cms a little bit more i found out that the code below solved my problem. It was more simple than I though. Hope this helps some other people too.

```
                {% set filerecord = record.file() %}

                    {% if record.file is not empty %}

                        {% for record in filerecord %}

                            <li><i class="fa fa-file-pdf-o"></i><a href="{{ paths.files }}{{ record.filename }}" title="Download">{{ record.title }}</a></li>

                        {% endfor %}

                    {% endif %}
```